# Rsync fails with exit code 23 only when run from Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, rsync, exit-code

I am using the [`rsync` module](https://npmjs.org/package/rsync) with Node `v0.10.22`. Rsync exits with code `23` (Partial transfer due to error) when run from Node, but succeeds when run from the same exact shell as the crashed Node process.

Here is the code I am using:

```
var r = new Rsync()
  .flags('a')
  .include('*.png')
  .exclude('*')
  .source(path.join('source/*'))
  .destination('target')
  .execute(function (err, code, cmd) {
    if (err && code === 23) {
      console.log('Exited with 23');
      console.log(cmd);
    }
  });
```

The `cmd` that is logged is as follows:

```
rsync -a --include="*.png" --exclude="*" source/* target
```

When I execute that exact command after Node crashes in the same shell the command returns `0` (no errors, it worked).

I have looked at `rsync.js` where it spawns the command:

```
// Execute the command as a child process
var cmdProc = spawn(this.executable(), this.args(), { stdio: 'pipe' });
```

`this.executable()` returns `'rsync'`. `this.args()` returns `['-a', '--include="*.png"', '--exclude="*", 'source/*', 'target/']`.

What is going on here? Why do I get a different exit code when running from Node as opposed to running in the same shell as where I run Node?

**Edit:** I set the permissions on each directory to be `777` and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: in what `cwd` that `spawn` is running?

Comment: Add `console.log(err)` as well and add it to your post. There should be some more information on the reason why it failed.

Comment: The paths are actually absolute, so it shouldn't matter. I shortened them for the sake of this question. Just to be sure, I changed the `spawn` command to have a `cwd` property set to my project's root directory and I am still having the problem.

Comment: Added `console.log(err)` which logged `[Error: rsync exited with code 23]`. Added `console.log(require('util').inspect(err))` which logged the same thing.

Comment: Also, nothing is coming across on `stderr`.

Answer (score 1):

The glob in the source isn't expanded, so rsync tries to find a file named `*` in the `source` directory.  Change the source to `source/`.